# Ravendb / F# / Linq

Tags: linq, f#, ravendb

I am new to ravendb, and I have 2 questions;

- I have around 65k objects stored there, but only 128 are returned back : why is it the case ? (using Robert P. OpenInitializedStore extension)

  ```
  let printStoreData() =
      use store = DocumentStore.OpenInitializedStore() 
      use session = store.OpenSession() 
      let qs = session.Query<DataModel.simplequote>()
      printfn "%A" (qs.ToList() |> Seq.length )

  printStoreData()
  ```
- I am quite confused about the relationship between Linq and Fsharp, f# query expression and Linq, query expression and Ravendb. I even see some Linq in the powerpack. Can anyone give me a high level view of what fits where, or point to a document that does ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Raven DB pages results to stop you accidentally returning too much data and overloading your system (which is a common source of performance issues in SQL based systems). You need to use Seq.skip and Seq.take to get the rest of your results. (It could also be because in RavenDB indexes are processed asynchronously so results are not available immediately after they are saved, but this seems less likely to be the cause of the problem in this case).

To answer the second part of the question:
The C# has expression trees, in which a C# linq expression can be transformed into a syntax tree by the the compiler instead of generating the actual code. RavenDB takes advantage of this to translate queries expressed as linq expressions into queries that can be run against RavenDB. F# has a similar facility to C#'s expressions trees called quotations. Quotations use different, F# specific types, to represent the code that has been quoted. In many ways quotations are more powerful that the C# equivalent, but RavenDB like most tools, uses C# expressions trees rather then F#'s quotations. To get round this there is library that's part of the F# power pack that can translate F#'s quotations to C# expression trees.

I have had limited success using the power pack to translate quotations to C# expression trees. I found that using raven db's 'lucene api', which doesn't rely on either quotations or expression trees.

Comment: i just saw that. http://old.ravendb.net/documentation/safe-by-default. thank you very much for the guidance .

Comment: @JoelMueller would you have any example to bootstrap ?

Comment: @nicolas you can find a whole bunch of F# 3.0 LINQ examples here: http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/